# Regex not matching the pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create a regex for the below data

```
12/07/16, 2:18 AM - ABC1: Anyway... this is ... abc: !?

:) Yea, this is next line - Multi line statements
12/07/16, 2:19 AM - User27: John, Bob, Him, I, May,2 ,3 100... multiple values
10/07/16, 2:41 PM - ABC1: Singe line statements
10/07/16, 2:41 PM - ABC1: Good
10/07/16, 2:45 PM - ABC1: Emojis statements, multiline, different languages
```

My Regex -

```
(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{2})\,\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s\-\s
```

The above regex works perfectly fine till

```
12/07/16, 2:18 AM -
```

My attempt to handle last bit (Username + message)-

```
(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{2})\,\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s\-\s(^[A-Z][0-9]$)
```

This fails to pick the message or username.

I am struggling to create the regex for the message piece as it involves newline characters, whitespace, emojis, different languages and I don't know the length of USERNAME or the MESSAGE.

I'm using [Debugger](https://www.debuggex.com/) to verify my regex and this [cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python)

I'm open to any improvements and suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: i saw this type of question yesterday and the solution was essentially spliting the message initially by '-', then ',' and then ':' and it seem to work better than regex.

Comment: @MEdwin well, not in this case IMO, consider that the message part can contain '-', ',' or ':' here

Comment: Read file line by line, check if line starts with your `^\d{1,2}/\d{2}/\d{2},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s\w{2}\s-\s` pattern (or just use it with `re.match(reg, line)`), if it matches and the entry text is empty, start a temporary entry and if the text is not empty push the entry text to the resulting list, if it does not match add the line to the entry.

Comment: but if you look closely; everything after the second ':' is your message and it seems to work all the time.

Comment: @Kaddath You can still use `str.split` with the `maxsplit=1` parameter to split the string at the first occurence of either `-` or `:` characters.

Comment: Check [my approach](https://ideone.com/5PUS6Q).

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://regex101.com/r/pLUgL7/1) is a bit of modification of your regex

```
(?s)(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{2})\,\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s\-\s(User\d+):\s*(.*?)(?=(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{2})\,\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s\-\s|\Z)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?s) #Dot matches new line
(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{2})\,\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s\-\s #Same as above
(User\d+)\s*:\s* #Match username followed by :
(.*?) #Find the message lazily till the below conditions
(?=
   (?:\d{1,2}\/\d{2}/\d{2})\,\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s\-\s  #Till the same format is found
   |
  \Z #or we reach end of string
)
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned in comment, the file should be in memory in a single variable

Comment: You should mention that for this regex to work the whole file should be read into a single variable.

Comment: @PirateX replace `(User\d+)` with `([\w-]+\d+)`.. I think you can figure that out.. 

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to read the whole file into memory. You may read the file line by line, checking if your start line pattern matches, then keep on adding lines to a temp string if they do not start with that pattern, and append to the result (or write to another file, to dataframe, etc.) when the end of file or another line that matches your datetime pattern is found:

```
import re
values = []
start_matching = False
val = ""
r=re.compile(r"\d{1,2}/\d{2}/\d{2},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s\w{2}\s-\s")
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if r.match(line.strip()):
      start_matching = True
      if val:
        values.append(val.rstrip()) # stripping trailing whitespace and write to result
        val = ""
      val += line
    else:
      if start_matching:
        val += line

if val:
  values.append(val.rstrip()) # stripping trailing whitespace and write the tail to result
```

If you use

```
for v in values:
  print(v)
  print("-------")
```

the output will be

```
12/07/16, 2:18 AM - ABC1: Anyway... this is ... abc: !?

:) Yea, this is next line - Multi line statements
-------
12/07/16, 2:19 AM - User27: John, Bob, Him, I, May,2 ,3 100... multiple values
-------
10/07/16, 2:41 PM - ABC1: Singe line statements
-------
10/07/16, 2:41 PM - ABC1: Good
-------
10/07/16, 2:45 PM - ABC1: Emojis statements, multiline, different languages



-------
```